# Saving data in json format using c#

Tags: c#, json

I want to save data in local json file in this format:

```
[
{"Name":"sdafdsf","Password":"dsfads","FirstName":"fsdf","LastName":"dsfdafas"},
{"Name":"sddafdsf","Password":"dsfadds","FirstName":"fdsdf","LastName":"dsfdafasdfs"} 
]
```

I am using this in the controller to serialize into json format:

```
 public ActionResult Index(demo obj)
        {

            String json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/app/");
            //// Write that JSON to txt file,  
            //var read = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path + "output.json");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "output.json",  json);
            return View();
        }
```

This is my model:

```
public class demo
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

But instead of proper JSON format I am getting this in my output.json file:

```
{"Name":"sdafdsf","Password":"dsfads","FirstName":"fsdf","LastName":"dsfdafas"}{"Name":"adfsdsfsafdsafasdfsdfsadf","Password":"dfsaasdsa","FirstName":"safd","LastName":"dfsafads"}
```

How can I save data in the proper format?

Comment: The format you show would require serializing an array of demo, so something like `List<demo>` would be easy.

Comment: Your first listing is an ARRAY. And your code manipulates ONE object.

Comment: If I use List<demo> then data will store in that format but if I add another data then It will In this format :::  [{"Name":"sdafdsf","Password":"dsfads","FirstName":"fsdf","LastName":"dsfdafas"}][{"Name":"adfsdsfsafdsafasdfsdfsadf","Password":"dfsaasdsa","FirstName":"safd","LastName":"dfsafads"}]

Comment: It sounds like you need to change your code so that your `ActionResult` is called only once when you have a completed array of `demo` to pass to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the proper format, if you mean you need it like an array then add the object to an array and after that serialize it:

```
 public ActionResult Index(demo obj)
        {
    var array = new [] {obj};
            String json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array);
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/app/");
            //// Write that JSON to txt file,  
            //var read = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path + "output.json");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "output.json",  json);
            return View();
        }
```

Or:

```
var list = new List<demo>();
list.Add(obj);
String json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

if you want to keep data always in an array then you always need to:

1. read data from the json file.
2. desalinize as a list of `List'.
3. add the new item to this list.
4. serialize it again and save it over that file replacing all the old text with the new one.

like this:

```
 public ActionResult Index(demo obj)
        {
          string path = Server.MapPath("~/app/");
        var read = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path + "output.json");
        List<demo> lst = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<demo>>(read);
        if (lst == null)
        {
            List<demo> _data = new List<demo>();
            _data.Add(obj);
           String json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data.ToArray());
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "output.json", json);
        }
        else
        {
            lst.Add(obj);
            String json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "output.json", json);
        }
        return View();
        }
```

Of course you can write cleaner code by separate some pieces.

Comment: IN output.json format is like ::: 
[{"Name":"asdfdsfsadf","Password":"adfasdf","FirstName":"fasdf","LastName":"asdf"}][{"Name":"asdfdsfsadfsaf","Password":"adfasdffsadds","FirstName":"fasdffdsfds","LastName":"asdffsdfsdf"}]

Comment: getting error at lst.Add(obj) :: ERROR == Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Thanks I accept your answer , and please up my question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a List of objects first and then try to Serialize the list. I'm sure you will get the desired output. Seems like you used AppendAllText method by Serializing single object.